# Moving player using keyboard listeners

Tags: c++, keyboard, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've got a player class, having `MoveUp`, `MoveLeft` and `MoveRight` functions.
At `MainScene.cpp` (my only scene so far), I've got a listener

```
auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = CC_CALLBACK_2(MainScene::keyPressed, this);
keyboardListener->onKeyReleased = CC_CALLBACK_2(MainScene::keyReleased, this);

Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
```

Also, I've got a pointer `player`, defined by

```
this->player = rootNode->getChildByName<Player*>("Player1");
```

Also, I've got a function `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` in `MainScene`.
In `keyPressed` function, I was scheduling functions with if's:

```
if (keyCode == cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_D) { schedule(schedule_selector(MainScene::MoveRight)); }
```

But there was a problem, when I tried to do the same thing with objects instead of sprites and with functions located in separated class, not within the same file.
If I try to run code like this in `MainScene::keyPressed`:

```
if (keyCode == cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W) { this->player->MoveLeft(5); }
```

, `player` moves only once per key press (I want it to move till I release that key), and if I try to schedule it or do something like this, it doesn't work or there are errors.

I tried to make something with `CallFunc` and `CCCallFunc`, but nothing seems to work.
Could you please help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a method startMoving() and stopMoving() in Player class?
Something like this:

```
void Player::init(){
    scheduleUpdate()
}

void Play::startMoving(){
    isMoving = true;
}

void Player::stopMoving(){
    isMoving = false;
}

void Player::update(float delta){
    if(isMoving){
        //move player here
        sprite->setPositionX(sprite->getPositionX() + speed * delta);
    }
}
```

and then call them from keyPressed/keyReleased?

Comment: But your solution seems to be a bit less optimal, since update function would have to check every key that player has at every frame. And also there's a bit more writing, since every action needs a bool value

Comment: update() is called anyway on each frame and just checking bool value won't really increase frame rendering time unless you have millions of them (but GPU won't render so much anyway). Also why checking for every key? You just listen to keyboard events and when something changed you're updating "player" info (isMoving, direction of movement and maybe other stuff). This is how I think it should be done - player should "care" for himself and any movement logic should be inside it. If you have different kinds of objects to move you should create class with universal data and others will extend it.